How do I change the console font for psql in PostgreSQL 16.3?
I don't know how this has happened (I may have changed something in my PostgreSQL / psql settings) but now everytime I open the psql console I get the following error:
"WARNING: Console code page (850) differs from Windows code page (1252) 8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference page "Notes for Windows users" for details."
I've ran the suggested fixes in this post (psql shell uses code page 850, windows uses 1252. How to solve change console code page?) but none of them have resolved it for me.
The official PostgreSQL documentation for the version I'm running (version 16.3) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/app-psql.html says to fix this I need to run the 'cmd.exe /c chcp 1252' command (as in the post above), and set the console font to Lucida Console.
How do I set the console font? I can't figure it out and I can't find any pages on the internet that provide a suitable answer for my version of Postgres, version 16.3. I'm on Windows 10.
I've looked in File > Preferences (in PGAdmin) but I can't find a setting for fonts.
Can someone help me please? I don't want to have to reinstall Postgres if I can avoid it.
I've ran the suggested fixes in this post (psql shell uses code page 850, windows uses 1252. How to solve change console code page?) but none of them have resolved it for me.
I've looked in File > Preferences (in PGAdmin) but I can't find a setting for fonts.

